# Can I use foreach to match a label array to existing labels

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, label

The code I have is this:

```
labels[0] = this.label1;
labels[1] = this.label2;
labels[2] = this.label3;
labels[3] = this.label4;
labels[4] = this.label5;
```

Is there a shorter way to write this? perhaps using a foreach? I tried...

```
foreach (Label label in labels)
{
    labels[temp] = this.label[label];
}
```

But of course this.label[label] isn't correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put all your labels to array (labels will be added in same order as you added them to form):

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();
```

Or if you want to take only labels 1..5 and put them in ascending order by their id no matter when labels was added (assume all labels have names like labelN - otherwise you can use regex to check for name pattern `^label\d+$`):

```
var labels = (from l in Controls.OfType<Label>()
              let id = Int32.Parse(l.Name.Substring(5))
              where id >= 1 && id <= 5
              orderby id
              select l).ToArray();
```

Comment: you beat me with one second :D

Answer (score 2):

I assume `this` refers to your form,if so you can create an array of labels like this:

```
Label[] labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();
```